# How to iterate a string from front and back at the same time in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check whether a string is palindrome or not. I want the solution which iterates the string from front and back at the same time. Is there a python solution which does this with a single loop?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [extended slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices):

```
for front, back in zip(string, string[::-1]):
    print(front, back)
```

But if you just want to check if a string is a palindrome, you can simply do:

```
if string == string[::-1]:
    print("Palindrome")
```

Comment: Or if you fear that the string might be extremely long, such that using `zip` and `string[::-1]` will do a lot of unnecessary work in the case where there's an early mismatch, then `itertools.izip(string, reversed(string))`. Probably with an `islice` thrown in there too to only check halfway.

Answer (score 1):

```
input = '12321'
palindrome = True
for i in range(len(input)//2):
  if input[i] != input[len(input) - 1 - i]:
    palindrome = False
    break
print('Is palindrom: ' + str(palindrome))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like:

```
for i, item in enumerate(string):
    if item != string[-i]:
        return False #  is not a pallindrome
return True
```